# How to test for race conditions on Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, schedule

I would like to use [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to run some functions every x seconds. The functions modify a global Dataframe. I know that Pandas is not thread-safe, so I have added a lock to each function call to mitigate that.
The code below (a minimal example) works as expected but I am not sure how to check that no race conditions will ever be raised by this code.

Can anyone suggest how to properly test this? Or can I simply assume the code is theread-safe since it uses `with lock`?

```
import schedule
import time, datetime
import pandas as pd
from threading import Lock

data = [(3,5,7), (2,4,6),(5,8,9)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C'])
lock = Lock()

def job(lock):
    global df
    with lock:
        df = pd.concat([df, df.iloc[0:2]])
        print('J1', datetime.datetime.utcnow(), len(df), df.A.sum())
    
def job2(lock):
    global df
    with lock:
        df = pd.concat([df, df.iloc[0:2]])
        print('J2', datetime.datetime.utcnow(), len(df), df.A.sum())

schedule.every(0.75).seconds.do(job, lock=lock)
schedule.every(0.25).seconds.do(job2, lock=lock)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Your schedule is really demanding, why wouldn't you go for some other system designed for this (redis/postgres/mongo) instead of keeping everything in memory?

Comment: What happens when you blow your RAM?

Comment: I don't know of any way to verify beyond people examining the code for any unprotected code paths. Often missed is error paths. In your case, its not much of a deal (if concat fails, you don't assign) but more generally, if you are making multiple changes, you have to worry about unwrapping on failure.

Comment: @roganjosh This is a toy example. My real functions will query APIs to append new data to the Dataframe. I have ways for checking RAM usage, that is not a problem for now. About redis/postgres/mongo I would prefer using Pandas instead of setting up a database. I just want to be sure I can use it with threads without messing it up.